# React files not interacting properly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm making a basic react website and so far it has been working perfectly fine up until I add an app.js-like file and use that in my directory. My normal index.js file that renders the components is below

```js
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./Home";
import Games from "./Games";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="games" element={<Games />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

No matter what I do, I consistently get an error of `Uncaught Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.` in my console despite the fact that I am referencing my DOM element of the "root" div which does exist in my index.html file in my public folder. My index.html file is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and clearly has a div with the "root" id. I never touched the index.html file, but once I added my Home.jsx

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import VideoBg from './Components/VideoBg';

class Home extends Component {
  render() { 
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <VideoBg />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
 
export default Home;
```

It all of a sudden stopped working and reverting brings the same error. VideoBg.jsx being imported previously is (obviously there is more, this is the only key component the rest are basic import export)

```js
render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <video autoplay loop id="VideoBg">
          <source src={this.getDay}></source>
        </video>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Why am I getting the Target Container is not a Dom element error despite the index.html and everything else consistently working before. I've tried rendering the VideoBg component solely and similar debugging things, but I can constantly given the container issue.